# php.net documentation - overseas

Tags: php

When I'm overseas, php.net site keeps giving me the language of the region. Is there a way to force php.net to stick with English?

I start out with php.net and that's English.
I perform a search, boom, English is gone.

Comment: http://php.net/my.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver  Hey, that's cool! I didn't know that was there.

Comment: It's cookie based so if you are on different computers in different countries you'll need to set it each time.  But if you are on your own laptop it should stick until you delete cookies (if anybody does that).

Comment: AbraCadaver pease post your comment as answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, just download one of the CHM files found here 
http://php.net/download-docs.php

Note: Once downloaded,  right-click on your chm file and select properties. You will see an "Unblock" button. Click on it, otherwise it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Thanks Duane but AbraCadaver nailed it. :)

Comment: @Average Joe No problem. I've used the CHM file off my USB drive for so long, I never knew that option existed.